# Private package with public types

Tags: typescript, npm, package

I have created a private package `priv`. Now I want to create another package `pub`. `pub` should be public. Its code does not depend on `priv`, so `priv` would not be a dependency from the classical JS point of view.

However, I work with TypeScript and want `pub` to use and expose (only) the types from `priv` (both declared and generated ones, like for classes). One could imagine `pub` as a kind of API to a blackbox around `priv`.

How could I do this? The only solution I can imagine is to create another public package `priv-types`, which is automatically filled with content and compiled whenever `priv` is compiled.